# How to see the euro symbol in a json (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I would like to take the euro symbol and print with a json, but I do not know why my code is not working.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
   class DINHEIRO{

       private $valor;
       private $simbolo;

       public function setValor($valor){
           return $this->valor = $valor;
       }

       public function setSimbolo($simbolo){
           return $this->simbolo = $simbolo;
       }
       public function getValor(){
         return $this->valor;
       }
       public function getSimbolo(){
         return $this->simbolo;
       }
   }
   
   $value = new DINHEIRO();
   $value->setValor(6);
   $simbolo = "\xE2\x82\xAc";
   $value->setSimbolo($simbolo);
   echo $value->getSimbolo(); //Here is working
   echo json_encode(array('valorConvertido' => $value->getValor(), 'simboloMoeda' => $value->getSimbolo())); //Here is not working
   
?>
```

Here is the output:
€{"valorConvertido":6,"simboloMoeda":"\u20ac"}

How to fix it?

Comment: This is correct. It's still JSON after all. `\u20ac` is a valid representation of `€` in JSON. Once the JSON is deserialized again and printed, it will look as expected.

Comment: How to deserialized the json? because I want to see the symbol

Comment: You can see it in the browser console for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3eP9.png

Comment: thanks bro, now its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a format for storing and transmitting data from one system to another. To make sure strings aren't messed up during transmission, it represents non-printable and non-ASCII characters using escape sequences like the one you show. This is perfectly normal and fine.

When you come to actually *use* the data, you will turn it back into strings in whatever programming language you're using, and the actual Euro symbol will be there as expected.